# if statements may seems to be flipped

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I have an if statement where the app will put a modal view controller called `LoginViewController` on the condition that `dataCenter.usernameData` returns `(null)`, otherwise, it will continue running code. I've set it up to where it does return `(null)`. However, it seems that the statements have been flipped to where if `dataCenter.usernameData` is returned as `(null)`, then it will not add `LoginViewController` and instead continue running the code from the Parent View Controller.

Here is the code:

```
AppDelegate *dataCenter = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([dataCenter.usernameData isEqual: @"(null)"]) {

        ViewController *viewControl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginControllerNav"];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(didDismissSecondViewController)
                                                     name:@"SecondViewControllerDismissed"
                                                   object:nil];

        [self presentViewController:viewControl animated:NO completion:nil];

        NSLog(@"No username.");
    } else {

        NSLog(@"Username; continue running code.");
    }
```

Is this supposed to happen? Or am I doing something wrong? A side question: say I release it in this format in the App Store. Will it flip back to the correct way or will it just stay like this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the situation. Are you initializing `data.usernameData` as the string `@"(null)"`, or are you skipping initialization all together and leaving it `nil`?

Comment: try: 'if (!dataCenter.usernameData)'  -let me know

Comment: Right now, nothing is defining it expect the fact that it is an NSString. In other words, there is no line of code that says: `usernameData = @(null);`

Comment: @Ilario as a matter of fact, I did do that, and it presented the `LoginViewController`.

Comment: @Junior117 There's your trouble: usernameData is a `nil` object, and you're trying to compare it to the NSString `@"(null)"`.

Comment: @Matt So you're saying that when `(null)` is presented in the console, it actually means that the object is `nil`?

Comment: Exactly. Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will check if an object is nil or not:

```
if (!dataCenter.usernameData)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments discussion we can infer that `dataCenter.usernameData` was not initialized, and thus is a `nil` object.

When you perform your if statement

`if ([dataCenter.usernameData isEqual: @"(null)"])`

you are comparing a `nil` object to an instance of NSString, which will fail and follow into your `else` clause.

To remedy this, change your if statement to

`if (!dataCenter.usernameData)`

This will check that your property `usernameData` is not nil and step into your if clause.

Comment: @Ilario Oh. Sorry about that. At first, I thought it read `if (![dataCenter.usernameData isEqualToString: @"(null)"])`, but upon closer inspection, you are right. In all fairness, please add an answer so I can mark it as correct, since you did answer the question first.